# NSMutableArray Compare Different Count

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a problem for my new app :

I have two string :

```
NSString *string1 = @"Il alla a la prison sur le champ" 
NSString *string2 = @"Il alllla a la prissson sur le champ"
```

I make the arrays :

```
NSArray *arrayReference = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; 
NSArray *arrayUser = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

I compare the array :

```
NSMutableArray *arrayResult; 

for (int i = 0; i < arrayReference.count ; i++)
{
  NSString *stringReference = [arrayReference objectAtIndex:i]; 
  NSString *stringUser = [arrayUser objectAtIndex:i]; 

  if ([stringReference isEqualToString:stringUser])
  {
    [arrayResult addObject:stringUser]; 
  }
  else {
    [arrayResult addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<strong>%@</strong> <italic>%@</italic>",stringUser]; 
  }
}
```

Then i get :

```
NSString *stringResult = [arrayResult componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

So i can print :

Il **alllla** *alla* a la **prisssson** *prison* sur le champ

that's ok, i can get user's mistake.

But i have a problem when the arrays does not have the same count !

if i have :

```
NSString *string1 = @"Il alla a la prison sur le champ";
NSString *string2 = @"Il fjdbfds alllla a la prison fdnfs sur le cahmp";
```

I want to print :

Il **fjdbfds alllla** *alla* a la prison **fdnfs** sur le **cahmp** *champ*

The app crashes when i enter my for (...) because i'm trying to insert nil object to NSString

Please help me, paypal donation if needed.

Thanks for all.

For Martin the best dev in the world :

String Users : 
Il alla sur le champ a la prison juju, il descendit au cabanon du saltimbanque ; il l'appela par son nom, lui pris la main et lui parla. Il passa toute la journée auprés de lui, oubliant la nourriture et le sommeil, priant dieu pour l'ame du condamné et priant le condmané pour la sienne propre. Il lui dit les meilleures verite qui sont les plus simples. Il fut pere, frere, ami, eveque pour benir seulement. Il lui enseigna tout, en le rassurant et en le consolant. Cet homme allait mourir deseperer. La mort etait pour lui comme un abime. Debout et fremissant sur le seuil lugubre, il reculait avec horreur. Il n'etait pas assez ignorant pour etre absoluement indifferent. Sa condamnation, secousse profonde, avait en quelques sorte rompue ca et la autour de lui cette coison qui nous separe du lystere des choses et que nous appelons la vie. Il regardait sans cesse au dehors de ce monde ar ses breches fatales, et ne coyait que des tenebres. L'eveque lui fit voir une clarte.

String Reference : Il alla sur le champ à la prison, il descendit au cabanon du saltimbanque ; il l'appela par son nom, lui prit la main et lui parla. Il passa toute la journée auprès de lui, oubliant la nourriture et le sommeil, priant Dieu pour l'âme du condamné et priant le condamné pour la sienne propre. Il lui dit les meilleures vérités, qui sont les plus simples. Il fut père, frère, ami, évêque pour bénir seulement. Il lui enseigna tout,  en le rassurant et en le consolant. Cet homme allait mourir désespéré. La mort était pour lui comme un abîme. Debout et frémissant sur ce seuil lugubre, il reculait avec horreur. Il n’était pas assez ignorant pour être absolument indifférent. Sa condamnation, secousse profonde, avait en quelque sorte rompu çà et là autour de lui cette cloison qui nous sépare du mystère des choses et que nous appelons la vie. Il regardait sans cesse au dehors de ce monde par ces brèches fatales, et ne voyait que des ténèbres. L'évêque lui fit voir une clarté.

Result String : 
Il alla sur le champ **a** **à** la **prison juju**, *prison,* il descendit au cabanon du saltimbanque ; il l'appela par son nom, lui **pris** *prit* la main et lui parla. Il passa toute la journée **auprés** *auprès* de lui, oubliant la nourriture et le sommeil, priant **dieu** *Dieu* pour **l'ame** *l'âme* du **condmané** *condamné* et priant le condamné pour la sienne propre. Il lui dit les meilleures *verite* **vérités**, qui sont les plus simples. Il fut **père, frère,** *père,frère* ami, **eveque** *évêque* pour **benir *bénir* seulement. Il lui enseigna tout,  en le rassurant et en le consolant. Cet homme allait mourir **desperer.**  *désespéré.* La mort **etait** *était* pour lui comme un abîme. Debout et **fremissant** *frémissant* sur **le** *ce* seuil lugubre, il reculait avec horreur. Il **n'etait** *n’était* pas assez ignorant pour **etre absoluement indifférent** *être absolument indifférent.* Sa condamnation, secousse profonde, avait en *quelques* _quelque_ sorte **rompu çà** *rompu çà* et *là autour de lui cette cloison qui nous sépare du mystère des choses et que nous appelons* la **autour** *vie.* _Il regardait sans cesse au dehors_ de *ce monde par ces brèches fatales,* _et ne voyait que des ténèbres. L'évêque_ lui **cette coison qui nous separe du lystere des choses et que nous appelons la vie. Il regardait sans cesse au dehors de ce monde ar ses breches fatales, et ne coyait que des tenebres. L'eveque lui** fit voir une **clarte.** *clarté*

Comment: you are required to check my edited answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
NSString *string1 = @"Il alla a la prison sur le champ";
NSString *string2 = @"Il fjdbfds alllla a la prison fdnfs sur le cahmp";

NSMutableArray *array1 = [[string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *goodArray = [NSMutableArray array];

while ([array1 count] > 0 && [array2 count] > 0) {
    // Check if first word of array2 occurs in array1: 
    NSString *word = [array2 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSUInteger idx = [array1 indexOfObject:word];
    if (idx == 0) {
        // correct word
        [goodArray addObject:word];
        [array1 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [array2 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    } else if (idx == NSNotFound || idx > 4) {
        // extra word in array2
        [goodArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<strong>%@</strong>", word]];
        [array2 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    } else {
        // missing word from array1
        word = [array1 objectAtIndex:0];
        [goodArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<em>%@</em>", word]];
        [array1 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
// Remaining missing words:
for (NSString *word in array1) {
    [goodArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<em>%@</em>", word]];
}
// Remaining extra words:
for (NSString *word in array2) {
    [goodArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<strong>%@</strong>", word]];
}

NSString *stringCorrected = [goodArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@", stringCorrected);
```

*Output:*

```
Il <strong>fjdbfds</strong> <strong>alllla</strong> <em>alla</em> a la prison <strong>fdnfs</strong> sur le <strong>cahmp</strong> <em>champ</em>
```

or rendered as HTML:

Il **fjdbfds** **alllla** *alla* a la prison **fdnfs** sur le **cahmp** *champ*

Comment: @user2206906: So what is missing? Can you give an example?

Comment: Hard for me to give you example can we upload pictures ?

Comment: Why can't you show string1 and string2 and the expected result?

Comment: @user2206906: That is a lot of text. Can you tell me where exactly my code produces wrong output?

Comment: It is very hard to tell where it goes wrong, everything is ok until "ça et là" and the wrong text goes before the good one and it takes all sentences not just word, i'll try to upload a picture

Comment: Perhaps you should split the input into sentences first (using `componentsSeparatedByString:@"."`), and compare each sentence separately.

Comment: no if the user forget . everything will go wrong
i can't upload pictures i do not have enough reputation.
Martin you are my only hope.

Comment: please help :( i'll literally die

Comment: The problem is that at "ca et la" the "la" is a spelling error (missing accent), but there is "la vie" later in the text. Therefore the algorithm thinks that "la" is correct, but many words are missing. To fix that, you would need some "optimizing" algorithm that tries to match as many possible words in both directions. - So sorry, I can't offer a better algorithm at the moment.

Comment: Ok so i'm dead, thank you very much for your time Martin, you are the best.

Comment: @user2206906: I have modified the algorithm a bit (see `|| idx > 4`) so that it finds matching words only if they are not too far away. You can play with that number, I do hope that the output is OK now.

Comment: MARTIN YOU ARE MY HERO, how can i thank you ?
What do i need to change for the case of missing words ?

Comment: it works even if missing words, I love you martin, really, i wish you the best for the rest of your life.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayReference ; i++)
```

do

```
NSInteger index = 0;
for (NSString * stringReference in arrayReference)
{
   if(index < [arrayUser count])
   {
       NSString * stringUser = [arrayUser objectAtIndex: index++];
       ...
       ...
       // do your comparison here
   } else {
       // you need to decide what to do if stringUser would be NULL
   }
}
```

Comment: No this not working, this not want i wan to do, thank you for u time

Answer (score 1):

you are checking `i < arrayReference`. But arrayReference is a array, you must check against the number of items in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayReference count] ; i++) {
    NSString *stringReference = [arrayReference objectAtIndex:i];
    if([arrayUser count]> i) {
         NSString *stringUser = [arrayUser objectAtIndex:i]; 
         if ([stringReference isEqualToString:stringUser])
         {
            [arrayResult addObject:stringUser]; 
         } else {
            [arrayResult addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<strong>%@</strong> <italic>%@</italic>",stringUser]; 
         }
    } else {
        //do you want to do something if the second array does not contain more words?
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea i have forget the .count sorry :)

Comment: Then also the app is supposed to be crashed @user2206906

Answer (score 1):

In the following line

```
 [arrayResult addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<strong>%@</strong> <italic>%@</italic>",stringUser];
```

you have given two format specifiers`(%@)` here, but you given only one value. That is the reason fo r the crash.
This line should be like.

```
[arrayResult addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<strong>%@</strong> <italic>%@</italic>",stringUser,@"Some Text"];
```

Answer (score 0):

THe simple reason for your app crash count for "arrayUser" is less than the count of "arrayReference", & you are running loop for "arrayReference" , & trying to fetch value of "arrayUser"...

You need to apply following snippet in order to compare your two array

> THIS WILL HELP YOU TO COMPARE ANY DYNAMIC ARRAY

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrI count]; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < [arrJ count]; j++)
    {
        if ([[arrJ objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:[arrI objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[arrI objectAtIndex:i]);
        }
    }
}
```

where arrI = arrReference 
and

arrJ = arrUser

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: No, in example he has given doesn't contain the same count !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayReference count] ; i++)
{

    NSString *stringReference = [arrayReference objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *stringUser = @"";
    if (i<[arrayUser count]) {
         [arrayUser objectAtIndex:i];
    }

    if ([stringReference isEqualToString:stringUser])
    {
        [arrayResult addObject:stringUser];
    }
    else {

         NSString *tempString = @"";
        if ([stringUser length])
        {
            tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<strong>%@</strong> <italic>%@</italic>",
                          stringUser,stringReference];
        }
        else{
            tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<italic>%@</italic>",stringReference];
        }

        [arrayResult addObject:tempString];
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit : when there is a extra word everything next is false

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is convert the first string to NSDictionary. Since we dont care about values lets initialize them to zeros.

So this will look like `NSString *string1 = @"Il alla a la prison sur le champ"`

```
Il -> 0, alla ->0 a -> 0, la -> 0 etc.
```

Now iterate through the second string after converting to array. Create a new resultString.

```
for(iterate elements through array)
{
   check if the element exists in dictionary
   if(!exists)
   {
      concatenate the result string with element that does not exist
   }

   concatenate the result string with current element

}
```

I just gave a basic idea. There are few pit falls which you need to address. Ex what if the dictionary contains more strings compared to array etc.